# Swagger converting underscore to camelcase

Tags: swagger

So, I'm having trouble using an XML object definition with Swagger (Core 1.5.7). Here's my XML code:

```
<result status="ok">
    <another>
        <cards/>
        <customer my_super_id="2349027834"/>
        <someothers>
            <someother name="who-is-this" />
        </someothers>
    </another>
</result>
```

And here's my yml code:

```
result:
   type: object
   description: Some random description
   properties:
     status:
       type: string
       xml:
         attribute: true
     another:
       type: object
       properties:
         customer:
           type: object
           properties:
             superId:
               type: string
               xml:
                 name: my_super_id
                 attribute: true
```

I can get the `status` with no problem, but the `my_super_id` is `null` because Swagger is generating the model class with the parameter in CamelCase, i.e., `mySuperId` instead of `my_super_id`.
In my generated model class I have this:
`public ResultAnotherCustomer(@JsonProperty("mySuperId") final String mySuperId)`

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: When you say model class is that in your server code? Who specifically is throwing the error? Is it the XML deserializer?

Comment: Yes, the model class generated by Swagger during the build. I've added additional info to the post, namely the CamelCase output in the generated model class.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something - why can't you just change the model so it says @JsonProperty("my_super_id")?

Comment: The model is being auto-generated from what I have in the yml file. I figured this is an error related to the swagger-codegen, but I don't know why.

Comment: Yes, my mistake on not using the latest version. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid as it is, it seems I wasn't using the latest version of `swagger-codegen`
, so updating it to the latest version (2.1.5) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue in Java Springboot App using Swagger Open API Specification. I ended overidding a Bean to make it work. But again this is how I fixed in Springboot with OAS.

```
@Bean
public ModelResolver modelResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return new ModelResolver(objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Old topic, but I had the same issue when generating typescript-angularjs directly from swagger.io. Snake -> Camel conversion.
A modelPropertyNaming has to be configured to snake_case when generating code, by default it is Camel.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/FAQ#typescript

Example using docker.

```
docker pull swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli

docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/local swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli generate -i /local/swagger.yaml --additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=snake_case -l typescript-angularjs -o /local/typescript-angularjs/
```

If it can help some of you, fellows. It is great.

Comment: This was the important piece for me: `--additional-properties modelPropertyNaming=snake_case`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My experience working with the Swagger coder generator is that it gets me about 80% of what I want and then I have to do the rest myself. If you think this is a bug than you can log it here:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Java generally favors CamelCase over snake_case so I'm guessing that it's intentional.

Comment: Can you share a bit more about the rest that you need to do manually? Thanks. Please share your feedback with us via https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Answer (score -1):

I also had this issue when generating a swagger client

The models were renamed from snake case 'aa_ba_ca' to camel case 'AaBaCa'

Error arose as no model was found when calling api_instance.method(swagger_client.model(parameters))

Error:
AttributeError swagger module  has no attribute