# How to convert API response parameters to snake case in Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I've changed my API response parameters to snake case by adding below line in `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
        };
    }
}
```

Currently I'm generating API documentation by using Swagger and I'm looking for same setup in Swagger response? Is there any option in Swagger for this?

Current document Output:

[image]

Expected document Output:

[image]

Comment: Try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552567/web-api-2-how-to-return-json-with-camelcased-property-names-on-objects-and-the

Answer (score 1):

Try using an `IDocumentFilter`, you can do all kind of changes to your document output (*aka `SwaggerDocument`*)

[Here are some examples on GitHub](https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L261)

Answer (score 1):

[Swagger Snake Case Configuration in Springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68860368/4564749)

I faced the same issue and was able to fix it using ModelResolver from Swagger OAS.